# Is Student's t test a Wald test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Is Student's t test a Wald test?

I've read the description of Wald tests from Wasserman's *All of Statistics*.

It seems to me that the Wald test includes t-tests. Is that correct? If not, what makes a t-test not a Wald test?

Comment: The Wald test statistic is almost but not exactly equal to the square of the t-test statistic - see the accepted answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60438/are-t-test-and-one-way-anova-both-wald-tests

Comment: @sed so the t-test is not a Wald test?

Comment: when *n* is large, the t-test is **essentially** identical to the wald test.

Comment: @sed what are the "essential" elements of the tests that compare identical? Are you saying the t-test **is the** wald test when n is large? What aspects are not identical when n is large?

Answer (score 33):

As Wasserman defines the Wald test, the *statistic* used in the t-test is the Wald-statistic defined there (aside, perhaps, from a  scale factor in the estimate of the standard error that asymptotically goes to $1$):

$$W=\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_0}{\hat{\text{se}}(\hat{\theta})}$$

However, the Wald test uses an asymptotic argument to compare that statistic with a standard normal distribution (asymptotically such a scale factor disappears). [The [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test_on_a_single_parameter) when dealing with a single parameter can be cast either as a Z-test or a chi-square; in the section being discussed, Wasserman is talking about the Z-form; if you square it, you would have the chi-squared form.]

The *t-test* relies on an exact small-sample argument to compare the test statistic with a t-distribution.

So, to answer your title question, strictly speaking, no the t-*test*  is not a Wald test.

Note, though, that they're asymptotically equivalent (i.e. as the sample size, $n\to\infty$, they will reject the same cases); certainly some people - if a bit loosely - call a test based on a t-statistic a Wald-test, whether the statistic is compared with the asymptotic normal distribution or the small-sample result (t-distribution).

Answer (score 2):

@Glen_b has provided an excellent answer to the topic. I want to add that, in the t-test, the distribution is the t-distribution. For example, you'd need to know the degree of freedom for your statistics. However, the wald-test relies on the chi-square distribution (square of standard normal). Of course, as the degree of freedom goes to infinity, they're both asymptotically equivalent.

One would prefer only the wald-test for a sufficient large sample.