# Likelihood ratio, Wald, and Score are equivalent?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

In *Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models*, Agresti makes a comment on page 131 about likelihood ratio, Wald, and Score testing of regression parameters.

> For the best-known GLM, the normal linear model, the three types of
> inference provide identical results.

I tried this out in R to see what would happen, and I got different p-values when I did my own likelihood ratio test versus the default printout in "summary()" that uses Wald, so something about my interpretation of Agresti's comment is incorrect.

```r
set.seed(2020)
N <- 100
x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
err <- rnorm(N)
y <- 0.5*x + err
G0 <- glm(y ~ 1, family="gaussian")
G1 <- glm(y ~ x, family="gaussian")
test_stat <- summary(G0)$deviance - 
    summary(G1)$deviance
df <- dim(summary(G1)$coefficients)[1] - 
    dim(summary(G0)$coefficients)[1]
p.value <- 1-pchisq(test_stat, df)
p.value
summary(G1)$coefficients[2, 4]
```

However, I did a simulation of many repetitions to check for long-run performance, and the results are about the same.

```r
set.seed(2020)
N <- 100 # sample size
R <- 1000 # number of simulations
alpha <- 0.05
lrt_r <- wld_r <- rep(0,R)
for (i in 1:R){
    x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
    err <- rnorm(N)
    y <- 0.5*x + err
    G0 <- glm(y ~ 1, family="gaussian") 
                # intercept-only model
    G1 <- glm(y ~ x, family="gaussian") 
           # model with x as a predictor
    test_stat <- summary(G0)$deviance - 
    summary(G1)$deviance
    df <- dim(summary(G1)$coefficients)[1] - 
       dim(summary(G0)$coefficients)[1]
    
    lr <- 1-pchisq(test_stat, df) 
        # likelihood ratio test p-value
    wd <- summary(G1)$coefficients[2, 4] 
        # Wald test p-value
    
    # check if the p-values warrant rejection at the level of alpha
    #
    if (lr <= alpha){lrt_r[i] <- 1}
    if (wd <= alpha){wld_r[i] <- 1}
}

# Check the power of each test
#
sum(lrt_r)/R*100 # 70.4%
sum(wld_r)/R*100 # 69.9%
```

This is close enough to suggest to me that the difference is due to a finite number of repetitions and/or something about that particular 2020 seed (though seeds 1 and 7 also give likelihood ratio testing slightly higher power, which I find suspicious).

Is that what's going on in Agresti's quote, that the three methods may not give identical results on any particular data set but will have the same long-run performance on many samples drawn from the same population?

(I didn't address score testing here, and I am content to prioritize Wald versus likelihood ratio testing.)

**Reference**

Agresti, Alan. *Foundations of linear and generalized linear models*. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.

Comment: That's absolutely untrue. They are *asymptotically* equivalent, so unless $n=\infty$, they will differ a little bit. Small $n$? They can differ a LOT.

Comment: "As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the [Wald, likelihood ratio, and Score] tests have certain asymptotic equivalences. For the best-known GLM, the normal linear model, the three types of inference provide identical results." My impression, evidently wrong, was that the three converged as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but differed for finite $n$...except for the normal linear model, where they gave the same results. I think this warrants a new question, but if even the normal linear model only has asymptotic equivalence, what equivalence does the normal linear have that GLM in general lacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exact equivalence only holds if the error variance is known, see [Exact equivalence of LR and Wald in linear regression under known error variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276192/exact-equivalence-of-lr-and-wald-in-linear-regression-under-known-error-variance). Else, [Wald, likelihood ratio and Lagrange multiplier are related via $W\geq LR\geq LM$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449494/ranking-of-wald-lr-and-score-statistic-in-the-normal-linear-regression-model/449495#449495) in a normal likelihood framework and equivalence only obtains asymptotically, as illustrated by the slightly revised version of your code below.

```
set.seed(2020)
N <- 1000000
x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
err <- rnorm(N)
y <- err
G0 <- lm(y ~ 1)
G1 <- lm(y ~ x)
test_stat <- 2*(as.numeric(logLik(G1)) - 
    as.numeric(logLik(G0)))

p.value <- 1-pchisq(test_stat, 1)
p.value
2*(1-pnorm(abs(summary(G1)$coefficients[2, 3])))
```

Notice that the above mentioned ranking assumes that error variances estimates are based on the ML estimate $1/n\sum_ie_i^2$ instead of the unbiased estimate $1/(n-k)\sum_ie_i^2$. The t-statistic retrieved from `lm` uses the latter, so that it is not exactly correct that the squared t-statistic equals the Wald statistic, so that, as in the numerical example below where we have `summary(G1)$coefficients[2,3]^2<test_stat`, the ranking need not emerge. We would obtain the likelihood-based Wald statistic from `summary(G1)$coefficients[2,3]^2*(N-2)/N`, for which the ranking would again be satisfied.

```
set.seed(2020)
N <- 10
x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
err <- rnorm(N)
y <- err
G0 <- lm(y ~ 1)
G1 <- lm(y ~ x)

# LR
2*(as.numeric(logLik(G1))-as.numeric(logLik(G0)))
N*log(sum(resid(G0)^2)/sum(resid(G1)^2))

# squared t-stat 
summary(G1)$coefficients[2, 3]^2

# Wald
N*(sum(resid(G0)^2) - 
    sum(resid(G1)^2))/sum(resid(G1)^2)

# corrected squared t which equals Wald
abs(summary(G1)$coefficients[2,3])^2*N/(N-2)
```

Comment: So somewhere in the `glm` function I used, it is estimating the variance, causing the slightly different results?

Comment: Yes, that is my reading of the situation. Indeed, the known error variance case is basically pedagogical in nature, I'd say, so that, while I do not know `glm` in detail, I have no reason to suppose it would not estimate the variance, as does `lm`.

Comment: By $W>LR$ do you mean the Wald stat is greater? Then wouldn't the LRT be UMP?

Comment: Yes, greater. Since we reject for large values, I would not infer UMP, no.

Comment: @AdamO, I made an edit which (was in any case necessary for me...) hopefully clarifies the relationship between the squared t-statistic and the Wald statistic. The issue is also discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115360/is-students-t-test-a-wald-test/115386#115386

Comment: I also post a new Q&A here, which discusses the ranking: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449494/ranking-of-wald-lr-and-score-statistic-in-the-normal-linear-regression-model/449495#449495