# the Wald, Likelihood Ratio (LR) the Lagrange Multiplier (LM) test statistics Are monotonic function of F statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio, lm, wald-test

Consider a classic linear regression model.

I want to show that the Wald, Likelihood Ratio (LR) the Lagrange Multiplier (LM) test statistics for the null hypothesis $H_0: R\beta =r$ for a constant vector $r$ are all monotonic functions of the standard F statistic.

Please suggest a book or document which show this theoretical proof.

Update: I found [the article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0165176581900264?via%3Dihub) which exactly proves the statement in this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Likelihood ratio, Wald, and Score are equivalent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449344/likelihood-ratio-wald-and-score-are-equivalent)

Comment: Exactly no. I want to theoretically prove that these tests follows F distribution (with mathematical proving ways) @Dave

Comment: I thought that answer addressed the inequality. [It’s in a follow-up.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/449495/247274)

Comment: @Dave I found its proof. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0165176581900264?via%3Dihub  Thank you.

Comment: You might consider typing up an answer to close out this question. Self-answers are not particularly common, but they are not frowned-upon. (I have done it a couple of times.) That also gives you a chance to evaluate your knowledge: if the post gets downvotes or other negative feedback, it could signal a gap in need of filling.