# Granger Causality and F statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, f-statistic

I am trying to educate myself in Granger Causality reading the classic literature.

From what I have understood the idea is quite simple: first, to test if $X_t$ Granger causes $Y_t$ we define two autoregressive models:

$$
\begin{align}\label{eq:varmodel}
    \tag{Full model}
    Y_t &= \sum_{j=1}^p a_j Y_{t-j} + \sum_{j=1}^q b_j X_{t-j} + \epsilon_t~, \\
    \tag{Reduced model}
    Y_t &= \sum_{j=1}^p a_j Y_{t-j} + \epsilon'_t ~,
\end{align}
$$
in other words in the reduced model we predict $Y$ just using its own past and in the full model we add $X$'s past states.

**Granger Causality** quantifies the "gain" in linear predictability and can be tested using the following statistic
$$
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}_{X\rightarrow Y} = \ln{\frac{\Sigma_R}{\Sigma_F}}~,
\end{equation}
$$
where $\Sigma_F= var(\epsilon_t)$ and $\Sigma_R = var(\epsilon'_t)$.

Does the quantity $\mathcal{F}$ follow the F-distribution? Because this would be crucial to calculate the p-value for a test. The problem is that I don't see where the F-distribution came from. The main problem is the presence of the logarithm. Shouldn't the F-statistic just be a ratio of two sums of residual squares?

In particular, from what I have understood (but correct me if I'm wrong), in a regression problem, F-test is used to see if a full model with $(p+q)$ parameters explains more variance of a restricted model with just $p$ parameters, so my intuition says that this is the case of Granger causality. On the other hand, F statistic should be a ratio of two sums of squares $SSR$ reflecting different sources of variability, but scaled on the number of parameters $p$ and the number of points $N$, so something like
$$F = \frac{(SSR_{R}-SSR_{U})/p}{SSR_{U}/(N-p-1)},$$
where $SSR_R$ and $SSR_U$ are the residual sum of squares of restricted/unrestricted model, respectively.

Finally, quoting [Geweke 1982], when referring to this object $\mathcal{F}$, he says that

> If autoregressions are really of order $p$ and the disturbances $\epsilon$ are Gaussian, these are maximum likelihood estimates conditional on presample values of $X_t$, and $Y_t$

I don't understand this point either, why is $\mathcal{F}$ is a *maximum likelihood estimates*?

[Geweke 1982] Geweke, John. "Measurement of linear dependence and feedback between multiple time series." Journal of the American statistical association 77.378 (1982): 304-313.

Comment: Since the test is implemented via linear regression, this may be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449344/likelihood-ratio-wald-and-score-are-equivalent/449362#449362